# DOC to PDF conversion, why does FileOutputStream generate corrupted pdf?

Tags: java, file, fileoutputstream

I have tried this code to convert a Word Document to PDF.

```
import java.io.*;
class DocToPdf {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/Samudra Ganguly/Desktop/ABC.docx");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/Samudra Ganguly/Desktop/ABC.pdf");
        int i;
        while ((i = fis.read()) != -1) {
            System.out.println(i);
            fos.write(i);
            fos.flush();
        }
        fis.close();
        fos.close();
    }
}
```

The PDF is created but cannot be opened. Can anyone explain the cause of the problem and the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The underlying syntax of `PDF` and `DOC` files are totally different.
- Doc is the binary format of a word document, developed by Microsoft.

  Here's the [MS Doc Specification](http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/B/E/0BE8BDD7-E5E8-422A-ABFD-4342ED7AD886/Word97-2007BinaryFileFormat(doc)Specification.pdfhttps://).
- PDF is developed by Adobe.

  Here's the [pdf format specification](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/pdf_reference_archives/PDFReference.pdf).

Their architecture is totally different. So just read from one `doc` file and try to write it into another file with `.pdf` extension, which will create nothing but a corrupted file. But if you save it with `.dox` format or open it `as doc`, then you can read it without any issue.

That's why you failed to open the created(and corrupted) file.

Comment: So, is there any way to convert it using input and output streams?

Comment: Logically possible. If you map doc syntax with identical pdf syntax, then start conversion then it will be possible.

Comment: If you think this question will help others with similar queries in the future, kindly upvote it.